# XSL 2.0 avoiding duplicate outputs from xsl:result-document

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using xsl:result-document to split an input XML file into multiple child documents.  When my transform is run over a large array on input files, a couple of the inputs 'have data' such that xsl:result-document tries to create the same output file twice and thus runs into an error.

Ideally, I'd like to simply create a second document with '_2' appended just before the file extension.  I am new to XSL 2.0 and cannot visualize how I could accomplish this.  Having an array (more like a map) that was global to the document that I could keep each output filename used in (along with a counter) would be great.  Doing this in XSL seems like no simple task though.  Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about this?

The scope of XSL variables is confusing to me and I am wondering if this is even possible.  If, for instance, I create a variable in the first template that matches, is that variable visible in the templates called as as result of an apply-templates 'call' from the first template to match?

Another idea, can some crazy 'identity transform' be used to find the duplicates and append '_2' to the data before further template matching occurs?

Thanks for your time.

Edit with sample of result-document usage:

```
 <xsl:result-document href="{$directory_name}{$misc_string}.xml" format="MainOutput" cdata-section-elements="SomeSection">
```

Chris

Comment: If the file name isn't important, use `generate-id()` to build a filename. It's guaranteed to be unique. Otherwise you can most likely use `xsl:number` to help create the filename. If you give a small example of how you're creating the filename now, I can add an answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the help.  Let me know if you needed to see more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [generate-id()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-generate-id)...

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$directory_name}{$misc_string}{generate-id()}.xml" 
 format="MainOutput" cdata-section-elements="SomeSection">
```

You could also use [xsl:number](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-number), but without a working sample (XML and XSLT) it's hard to provide an example. (Context is very important.) This is most likely what it would look like:

```
<xsl:variable name="nbr">
    <xsl:number level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:result-document href="{$directory_name}{$misc_string}_{$nbr}.xml" 
    format="MainOutput" cdata-section-elements="SomeSection">
```

Take a look at the `xsl:number` link and play around with some of the attributes (like `@count`), and that should do it.